# Connectivity and Clustering using Eigenvectors and the Fiedler Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, clustering

Going off of the answer here:
[sorting adjacency matrix by the Fiedler vector](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10936/sorting-adjacency-matrix-by-the-fiedler-vector/10937#10937?newreg=ca06ec045dde4c48b62c60d45a4aacc8)

So here, Jesse the answerer plotted the first 3 eigenvectors associated with non-zero eigenvalues of the Laplacian against each other in order to see more distinguishable clusters.

My 2 questions about this are:

1) Why did he choose specifically the first 3 eigenvectors to plot, as opposed to for example, just the first 2?  Like what determines how many eigenvectors you should compare?

2) Is there a way to quantify connectivity between clusters?  For example, when looking at the graph Jesse originally made, is there a way to tell from plotting the eigenvector values that the top cluster is more closely connected to the second top most cluster than the bottom most cluster?